# Why are there so few politicians on the bottom right of the political spectrum?

Tags: libertarianism, political-spectrum

[image: Political Compass]

There are abundances of parties and politicians in all squares except the Libertarian Right, why is this?

Comment: Where did your quadrants diagram come from?  I ask because I don't consider those four quadrants to be the primaries.

Comment: @Venture2099 https://www.politicalcompass.org

Comment: False premise. Here in Switzerland most right-wing politicians are overwhelmy liberals, right-wing concervatives exists but are extremely in minourity, and they are (in my opinion, unfortunately !) regularly defeated in elections. Perhaps if you'd reduce the scope to a signle country this question is salvageable.

Comment: It is unclear to me what "right" and "left" indicate in your diagram.  The words don't have a consistent meaning in public discourse even within America.  I can't imagine what they mean in other parts of the world. To get a meaningful answer you need to state more clearly what the question is.  It would also help to clarify what you mean about one of the quadrants being underpopulated.  Are your referring to politicians worldwide or just in certain regions?

Comment: @Readin- the axis is marked "Economic scale", so these are left/right on economic liberties. (e.g. taxation, regulation, ownership of means of production etc...)

Comment: Why is this on hold?  Mods - this is not too broad at all and I have answered it.

Comment: I'm inclined to say there are no Libertarian Left parties. It's a logical contradiction: without a strong state, equality can't be enforced by the state. Not that such logic is stopping public opinion; "government should stay out of Medicare" is not a rare opinion in the US.

Comment: @MSalters: a fair number of attempts at a political compass identify left and right with with  individua versus property rights. In that viewpoint the various Pirate Parties qualify, as might the Greens. In general the debate is over which of the landowner verses hiker should end up with the right to shoot the other, whereas authoritarians would let the state do the shooting.

Comment: This question is void of a lot of context...we need a lot more info on the definitions of the terms used in that diagram--not to mention what political parties (and nations) you are referring to.

Comment: @MSalters The word libertarian had a leftist definition for much longer than it was defined as right wing.  I'm thinking anarcho syndicalism and that sort of thing.  Anarchists could be for or against private property.  One could argue right wing libertarians are a logical contradiction because without a strong state capitalism cannot be enforced.

Comment: @MSalters as I understand libertarianism, it expects juat a very few roles from government - but those roles do include protection of property rights and the enforcement of contracts (other roles are protection from assault and kidnapping). As such there is no logical contradiction in a capitalist libertarian society.